# React Native TV: Focus issue when 2 text inputs are align vertical

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-tv

hope you have a great day.

Currently my project is working on have this issue. On my screen, i have 2 `TextInput`, i can't use the d-pad to move up or down while text is empty but once it have been filled at least 1 character, the d-pad's up and down button work normally. I'm still looking for a solution for this, any ideas on what can cause this problem and how to fix it?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz77y.png))

Cause:

1. `TextInput` default `width` is 270
2. Press up and down on D-pad, it wont work

Expected:
When both `TextInput`'s `width` is 270, it should be able to lose focus and shift to next `TextInput`

While debugging i noticed that: when i set `height` to 108 (`width`/2.5), i can be able to move up and down by using the d-pad

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.